# Python Framework for Visualizing a Simulation

Tags: python

I've written some code to simulate the flight of drones, and I'm looking for a Python framework to do the following things: take in a map from some API (I'm currently thinking of using OpenStreetMap), set up waypoints with various pieces of information for the drone to visit, and then visualize the flight of the drone. Can anyone recommend a good Python framework to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) can do all that you want.